# Problem running google map in an android project

Tags: android

Am running a project on android using eclipse IDE , on trying to run the map view i could do that enabling the google map view and using the uses library . But when it comes to the AVD it shows an error. saying the target API is not ssupporting maps (I did try creating a new AVD). Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Please make your target as "Google APIs" corresponding to ur version which u want to use.

Answer (score 1):

From the name of your emulator.. I guess you will be using an app which has maps. If yes, you need to create the AVD using Google API with the right API Level (and not normal AVD). If you can't find Google API within your "Android SDK & AVD Manager", you need to install from the "Available Packages" option